# Bug in the display of blockquotes

Tags: support, code-formatting, blockquote

I've just posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078160/static-file-with-modwsgi-in-django) on Stack Overflow and noticed problems in the display of the blockquote.

Some parts of the code wasn't displayed at all. For example this piece of code which is on one line : `<html> <body> hello world </body> </html>` gives with blockquote :

> hello world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed your post but take a look to see if it is what you want.

You don't want to use block quotes. That is for quoting text passages. That will strip out your HTML.

What you want is "code blocks." That will post your literal text *exactly* as your enter it (with a bit of code prettifying).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **code sample** option to display code, not the **blockquote** option.

It's [Ctrl]+K or the "101010" icon to convert text already entered, or prefix each line by four (4) spaces.

```
Like this
```

Comment: Sweet.  I didn't know about CTRL+K.